# XeTeX can't find file with long name on Windows10

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, miktex, compiling, windows

I compile files from my current working project on Windows10. Files with short name are being compiled from .tex to .pdf successfully, but files with long name don't compile. I get this error:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `identify_conic_sections_written_in_rectangular_coordinates
_by_eccentricity_and_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_sol_1.tex'.
<*> ...d_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_sol_1.tex

Please type another input file name:
```

If I input name again, error repeats again.
I have standard TeX code with TikZ library and I need to generate only pdf-picture (graphs of formulas) from my code.

```
        \documentclass[tikz, border={8pt 14pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        …
\begin{document}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \begin{axis}[standard] \path(axis cs:0,0) node[anchor=north east] {0};
\addplot[name path=A, color=black, samples=100, ultra thick, domain=1:13] { 2*sqrt(1 - (x - 7)^2/36) + 5 };
        …
\addplot[solid, color=red, samples=41, ultra thick] coordinates { (7, 5.10000000000000) (4*sqrt(2) + 7, 5.10000000000000) } node[above, pos=.5, fill=white, font=\large] { c${}=4 \sqrt{2}$ };
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I can't make name of file and name of directory shorter because of this is GitHub-project with 20 different developers and our company can't make names shorter. Other developers mostly use MacOS, but I use Windows10. I can take MacOS, but this is a bit difficult. Also, it looks so stupid to change OS just because of XeTeX doesn't work with long names.

Do somebody have any idea, how to get XeTeX work with long names?
I'd be very grateful for answer.

Note:
I use Windows 10 latest version (1909). I already set up my Windows10 for long names in both PATH and Policies setting. Other utilities work now with long name. Git is set up for long names too. Just XeTeX (and other ***TeX) don't work with long names.
I already tested different other ways to solve problem:

- I updated all packets in MiKTeX
- I tried to check XeTeX with my scripts with short names (XeTeX works perfectly)
- I tried LaTeX, XeLaTeX, TeX - all these commands don't work with long names
- I used PyCharm terminal and standard Windows terminal to run ***TeX commands
- I even repeated everything on two different Windows10 computers. This awful problem repeated!
- I already googled and searched over tex.stachexchange.com this problem and I didn't find any information

Comment: I just tried to input such a file (with `\input{...}` in a small example and it worked fine. Your description is missing something. Perhaps something is adding a line break.

Comment: please post an example people can test, presumably the tikz isn't required to show the problem and you can show it with `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{a_very_long_name}
\end{document}` where `a_very_long_name.tex` is an empty file in the same directory?  Post an example that we can reproduce the error.

Comment: I also tried to compile such a file and it worked without problems.

Comment: oh no looking at your error (if that is the whole log) it is not an `\input` file but the filename on the commandline?

Comment: My code works perfectly if filename and dir.name are short. Of course, my example works on your computers. I have problem when I compile ANY .tex file with long name and long directory name. You can create any empty or not empty file with any long name like ``` "C:\Users\black\PycharmProjects\calculus-generators\Chapter 11\Identify conic sections written in rectangular coordinates by eccentricity and write the equation of the conic\images\identify_conic_sections_written_in_rectangular_coordinates_by_eccentricity_and_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_sol_1.tex" ``` and  check does it work or not

Comment: @david-carlisle, I don't use `"\input"`. I use the filename from commandline. :)

Comment: I can attach full text of my file, but this problem doesn't depend of content of my latex file. I get the same error  from commandline  with **ANY** _.tex_ file with long file name and long directory name. Long means >260 symbols in windows 10. I think that Linux and Macos don't have this problem, long name for Unix systems is 4096 symbols

Comment: I can't reproduce, (I don't have miktex, although I am on windows) but you could always use the  short name `IDENT~1` or whatever name  `dir /x` says it has.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess you could reproduce if you create the whole path mentioned - it exceeds in length the MAX_PATH value of 260 and so no longer work.

Comment: @PavelMikhailov I will not start to mess around with my registry to try out if long names work or not. If you think that you correctly enabled them and the miktex binaries don't honor this, add an issue at the miktex issue tracker. The maintainer is the only one who can do some about it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for advice. Your answer sounds good. I checked now names by dir /x, my file is IDENTI~1.TEX. I tried **xelatex IDENTI~1.TEX**, but I got the same error ` I can't find file `./identify_conic_sections_written_in_rectangular_coordinat
es_by_eccentricity_and_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_sol_3.tex'. ` - it looks like xelatex gets back full name of file after IDENTI~1.TEX and breaks again

Comment: @UlrikeFischer _I am sure that I configured Windows 10 right._ Other (not-...TeX) programs did not work with long names before configure, but they work now (after configure). Just ...TeX commands don't work. I understood your advice. I will make more attemps tomorrow. If no result, I will add **issue at the miktex issue tracker for the maintainer** Thx

Comment: Do it. But imho your naming system is madness. I mean you can't even ask someone with a standard windows for help without first renaming everything. And how do you find a file? I have already forgotten the begin when I'm reading the end.

Comment: Right now I got and idea. I have compiled my .tex files from _graphical program "TeXworks"_ and compiled my *super_long_name.tex* in xelatex mode. AND … IT WORKS! Other long names work too. But *this is not solution* for me because of I need compile them from `command line`. I have to compile tens and hundreds of .tex pictures to .pdf automatically, I can't spend time for every .tex file in graphical interface of "TeXworks"

Comment: texworks is not compiling anything it is just calling tex in the background so whatever it is doing to call xetex you can do the same from the commandline

Comment: or is your issue the cmd shell itself, can you use a git bash shell or powershell or any other commandline (just guessing here, I never use the cmd terminal I use cgwin or wsl bash)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right. However, the same procedure works from TeXworks, but doesn't work from any command line, which I can run on my windows 10.

Comment: No if one works and one doesn't then it isn't the same procedure there must be a setting texworks is using that you are missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes! These _long filenames is obviously madness_ ! But my company pays for my work, other workers use macos, and I have to solve this problem. I get files from GitHub and *git works* (after configuring) perfectly with long names. But tex not!

Comment: @PavelMikhailov I have created an issue:https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/510

Can someone (maybe Ulrike?) try to reproduce this with TeX live and add a comment to the ticket?

Comment: @ChristianSchenk __great thanks__ for creating of issue! I will try to reproduce this issue on TeX live, but I have never worked with TeX live before.  If I get _any result_, I comment the ticket

Comment: @ChristianSchenk,  I Checked Tex Live. Error is identically the same.`This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992` **(TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)** `(preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file "identify_conic_sections_written_in_rectangular_coordinates
_by_eccentricity_and_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_1.tex".
<*> ...y_and_write_the_equation_of_the_conic_1.tex

Please type another input file name:`

Comment: Thank you, Pavel. Since Akira is already aware (see answer below) of the issue, it should not be necessary to report it to the TL mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be correct. But try to save files with names

```
xetex.exe.manifest
```

and/or

```
xelatex.exe.manifest
```

in the same directory as xetex.exe, xelatex.exe
with the following contents:

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
        <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you for idea. I checked, this does not work. I tried from different terminals. Also, I found that if I run xetex.exe, this terminal cuts all symbols after 260-th symbol authomatically (even before I press "Enter"). It's impossible to insert more than 260 symbols in window of "xetex.exe"

Comment: Sorry, `_MAX_PATH` is alive. Of course TeX Live for Windows also
have the limitation.

Comment: The manifest file approach should work provided that the executable hasn't an embedded manifest. But I think the manifest must be valid, i.e.,  the `application` section must be inside an `assembly` section. For example: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/blob/208dc67d3655d5e738402fd3c24ec835e87d386a/Resources/Manifests/common.manifest

Comment: @Christian Schenk: Many thanks. I did not know manifest files
and learned that the above was wrong and incomplete by seeing your
complete example.